# String передаётся по ссылке или по значению?

Tags: java

Вероятно запутался... Если String ссылочный тип

```
    String s1 = "123";
    String s2 = s1;

    s1 = "321";

    System.out.println(s1);
    System.out.println(s2);
```

то почему результат

```
321
123
```

а не дважды `321`? По

Comment: В памяти есть 2 ячейки в которых лежат строки `"123"`, `"321"` и есть 2 ссылки, которые тоже валяются в памяти в соответствующих ячейках. Первая имеет значение ячейки памяти где лежит "123" (указывает на "123") . Это значит что в ячейке, которая выделена под ссылку лежит значение, которое является номером ячейки памяти со строкой. теперь мы делаем `s2 = s1` - здесь значение в ячейке для s1 копируется в ячейку s2. Т.е. они обе указывают на "123" (заметьте, не s2->s1->"123", а s1 -> "123" и s2 -> "123"). Ну и естественно после изменения переменной s1 переменная s2 не поменяется.

Comment: @learp на самом деле там пул строк

Comment: @Санаев Ну я в курсе, только тут это не имеет значения. Если бы дело было не со строками, а, например с `new Object()`, то поведение было бы таким же (изменилась бы лишь одна ссылка, а не обе).

Comment: Отличайте объекты в куче (сами строки) и ссылки на них (именованные переменные). У вас две ссылки, которые сначала обе указывают на один объект (`"123"`), а потом одна из них перенаправляется на новый объект  (`"321"`).

Comment: Коротко, потому что ссылка ссылается на объект, а не на другую ссылку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первое что стоит понимать - все объекты лежат где-то в куче (на самом деле JIT/JVM может как-то изменить положение вещей для оптимизаций, но для понимания лучше считать, что все объекты лежат в heap).

Теперь пойдем по строкам. Я некоторые вещи упрощу, для того чтобы проще было понять саму суть. И обойду пул строк, будем считать, что никакого пула нет.

`String s1 = "123";` Здесь идет создание объекта String со значением "123" в куче, выделение памяти на стеке под ссылку и запись адреса памяти объекта String в эту выделенную ячейку.

`String s2 = s1;` Здесь выделяется место на стеке под новую ссылку s2, в которую записывается значение s1 - т.е. адрес памяти объекта String

На текущий момент получается такая картинка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`s1 = "321";` Здесь идет создание объекта String со значением "321" в куче и запись адреса памяти объекта String в s1.

s2 после последней операции никак не поменяла свое значение. Поэтому вывод корректен.

По поводу оптимизации расположения объектов в памяти можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html).

Про пул строк [есть хорошее видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZFe3m1DV1A).

Answer (score 1):

А почему должно поменяться значение в s2?  Ваш код можно записать по другому, и тогда я думаю станет понятно, почему такое поведение

```
String s1 = new String("123"); //ссылка раз
String s2 = s1; //копируется ссылка на объект

s1 = new String("321"); //ссылка 2, при этом в объекте s2 так и осталась ссылка на предыдущий объект
```

Ключевым моментом тут является то, что мы именно **копируем** ссылку при присвоении `s2=s1`, т.е. у нас в памяти теперь две ячейки с адресом одной и той же ссылки. И когда мы кладем в одну из них другую ссылку, это не приводит к изменению значения ссылки в другой ячейке.

Comment: а в чем же заключается ваш ответ? вы бы подробнее объяснили почему у s2 нет ссылки на s1

Comment: `//копируется ссылка на объект + копируется значение строки` - неправда, никакого копирования значения строки не происходит. Копируется лишь ссылка.

Comment: а вы попробуйте создать кастомный объект и проделать тоже самое, посмотрите что получится